# Pass new password value to validator.ts in Angular 4

Tags: forms, angular, custom-validators, angular-forms

I am working through the challenges for a Udemy course on Angular 4, but I am stuck on a challenge where I have to create an input for a new password and then another input to confirm the new password using reactive forms.

I have an external .ts file called password.validators.ts that has custom form validation code, and I can get the value of the currently selected input box by passing a control object with AbstractControl, but how do I pass a value to my component.ts file and then from my component.ts to my password.validators.ts ? I need to be able to compare the new password value to the confirm password value and I'm stuck!

**new-password.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="oldPassword">Old Password</label>
        <input
        formControlName="oldPassword"
            id="oldPassword"
            type="text"
            class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="oldPassword.pending">Checking password...</div>
            <div *ngIf="oldPassword.touched && oldPassword.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="oldPassword.errors.required">Old password is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="oldPassword.errors.checkOldPassword">Password is incorrect</div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newPassword">New password</label>
        <input
        formControlName="newPassword"
            id="newPassword"
            type="text"
            class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="newPassword.touched && newPassword.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="newPassword.errors.required">New password is required</div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="confirmNewPassword">Confirm new password</label>
        <input
        formControlName="confirmNewPassword"
            id="confirmNewPassword"
            type="text"
            class="form-control">
            <div *ngIf="confirmNewPassword.touched && confirmNewPassword.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="confirmNewPassword.errors.required">Confirm password is required</div>
                <div *ngIf="confirmNewPassword.errors.confirmNewPassword">Passwords don't match</div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Change Password</button>
</form>
```

**new-password.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PasswordValidators } from './password.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'new-password',
  templateUrl: './new-password.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-password.component.css']
})
export class NewPasswordComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    oldPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required, PasswordValidators.checkOldPassword),
    newPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirmNewPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required )
  })

  get oldPassword() {
    return this.form.get('oldPassword');
  }

  get newPassword() {
    return this.form.get('newPassword');
  }

  get confirmNewPassword() {
    return this.form.get('confirmNewPassword');
  }

  addNewPassword(newPassword: HTMLInputElement) {
    let np = this.newPassword;
    return np;
  }

}
```

**password.validators.ts**

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

export class PasswordValidators {


  static checkOldPassword(control: AbstractControl) : Promise<ValidationErrors | null> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          if(control.value !== '1234')
            resolve({ checkOldPassword: true }) ;
          else resolve(null);
      }, 2000);
    });
  }

  static confirmNewPassword(control: AbstractControl) : ValidationErrors | null {
          if(control.value === control.newPassword.value)
            return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following code for my password validation may be this can help you
In password.validator write this code

```
import {AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';
```

export class PasswordValidation {

```
static MatchPassword(AC: AbstractControl) {
   let password = AC.get('password').value;
   let confirmPassword = AC.get('confirmPassword').value;
    if(password != confirmPassword) {
        console.log('false');
        AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors( {MatchPassword: true} )
    } else {
        console.log('true');
        return null
    }
}
```

}

and in the component file use this code

```
constructor(fb: FormBuilder)
  {
    this.form = fb.group({
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {
      validator: PasswordValidation.MatchPassword // your validation method
    })
  }
```

and in html file to find error use this code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="form.controls.confirmPassword.errors?.MutchPassword">Password not match</div>
```

Hope it would help you